# How to use the Python version active in an Anaconda environment in CMake builds?

Tags: python, cmake, anaconda

I'm building [OpenVDB](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb#building-openvdb-2) on Windows 10 with Python support, but I need to compile it against Python 3.7.

The system-wide version of Python is 3.10 and the build works fine with that.

I use Anaconda to set up a Py3.7 environment with

```
conda create -n py37 python=3.7
```

Then I modify the `CMakeLists.txt` to look for this version of Python:

```
find_package(Python 3.7...<3.8 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development.Module Interpreter)
```

In this environment, without any other changes, CMake still finds the system version of Python:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python: Found unsuitable version "3.10.2", required range is
  "3.7...<3.8" (found
  C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/tools/python3/python.exe, found
  components: Development.Module Interpreter)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:592 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:3172 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPython.cmake:519 (include)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/python/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:67 (_find_package)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:761 (include)
  openvdb/openvdb/python/CMakeLists.txt:120 (find_package)
```

Adding `-DPython_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\py37\python.exe` at command line helps with finding the right the Python version, but there's still trouble with CMake:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Development.Module) (found suitable version
  "3.7.13", required range is "3.7...<3.8")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:3172 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPython.cmake:519 (include)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/python/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:67 (_find_package)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:761 (include)
  openvdb/openvdb/python/CMakeLists.txt:120 (find_package)
```

What is exactly `Development.Module`, and is it really missing from the environment?

If yes, then how do I install it?

If no, then what do I need to add to the CMake scripts or command line to make it work?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I did not write OpenVDB, I'm just using it. But thanks for the assumption :)

Comment: Have you done anything to hint to CMake about the location of your conda instalation of python? Ex. setting initial value of [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) (disclaimer: I don't know if `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` can actually solve the problem, but its documentation seems to fit the need here).

Answer (score 2):

If your cmake version is greater than `3.15`, you can first activate your `py37` and then run cmake with the `-DPython3_FIND_STRATEGY=LOCATION` option.

See the [FindPython3](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html#hints) for details:

> This variable defines how lookup will be done. The Python3_FIND_STRATEGY variable can be set to one of the following:
>
> - **VERSION**: Try to find the most recent version in all specified locations. This is the default if policy CMP0094 is undefined or set to OLD.
> - **LOCATION**: Stops lookup as soon as a version satisfying version constraints is founded. This is the default if policy CMP0094 is set to NEW.